# Xamarin : invalid configuration in Resource forlder

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add new values folder to my project to add a new language so when I try to create a new folder with string.xml and rebuild a project this error appear in the output

```
error APT2142: invalid configuration
```

and in the error list

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Source Suppression State
Error invalid configuration 'ku2'.  FILEPATH\Resources\values-ku2\strings.xml
```

Comment: why is it "values-ku2" and not just "values"?

Comment: I have 3 languages that's the reason , values-en , values-ar , values-ku. and trying to add another @Jason

Comment: try removing 2 from ku

Comment: the suffix needs to be a valid locale identifier for Android

Comment: after removing 2 the error disappeared , thank you ! @SaurabhDhage

Comment: tired the valid identifier it helped me too thank you @Jason